# Perl CGI::Session save_param saves all parameters as array under one key

Tags: perl, cgi, cgi-application

Im using `CGI::Session` to store session data from `CGI::Application` (specifically i'm using `CGI::Session` through the `CGI::Application::Plugin::Session` module).
In one of my application modes I do this:

```
    my $self = shift;
    # Get CGI query object
    my $q = $self->query();
    $self->session->save_param($q);
```

To save my parameters to the session data however on retrieving them using `$self->session->param('user')` I find that only the user parameter contains any data even though other parameters are being sent server side and are accessible through `$q->param()` the user parameter retrieved from the session is an array of the parameters, however i would expect that `$self->session->param('user')` would return a single string with the contents of the parameter 'user'.
Is this behavior expected?
If so why?

Comment: Can you show us what the data key/value pairs?

Comment: What does a Data::Dumper output of your `$self->session` look like? How can it even save the CGI object at all...?

Comment: It would also be helpful to see a Dump of $q and/or one of the output from $q->param()

Comment: I'm fairly new to perl and didn't know that there was any way to dump data, so thanks for that. After looking at the dump i then checked form that was sending the parameters, and saw that there were two fields called 'user', now I feel rather stupid, although that isn't what i thought would have happened from that mistake.

Comment: That happens. It's a lot more fun if you put all the params in a hash with `$q->Vars` and there are several fields with the same name, they end up in one string, concatenated with a `\0` char. Great, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but this looks weird. You're not doing what the [CGI::Session doc](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aSession) says you should. You can't just save the CGI object. You need to store each param individually.

> ```
> # Storing data in the session:
> $session->param('f_name', 'Sherzod');
> ```

If you want to just store all the CGI params in your Session, do it like this:

```
# $q := CGI object
# $session := CGI::Session object

$session->param('foo', $q->param('foo'));
$session->param('bar', $q->param('bar'));
```

Or you might even do it like this for all of them:

```
foreach my $key ($q->param) {
  $session->param($key, $q->param($key));
}
```

Comment: Actually the CGI::Session doc does include the save_param method which is supposed to be "the same as calling param($name, $value) for every single query parameter returned by $query->param()".  I haven't dug into the code yet, but I suspect that the CGI:App query object isn't doing the right thing with its param() method.